# Where is the unhandled promise? And why so many increments on count?

Tags: node.js, promise, transactions, knex.js, unhandled-exception

I am looking for the unhandled promise that gives an error when I execute the following method and I also want to understand why the count is incremented so many times if the method is only called as stated above.

```
function StorePoint(this: PointsModel, collectedItemsIDs: number[]): Promise<Array<any>> {

    console.log(this.count++);
    return knex.transaction(trx => {

        return Promise.all([
            trx('points').insert(this),
            trx('items').select('id'),
        ]).then(([insertedPointIDs, allItemsObjs]) => {

            const insertedPointID = insertedPointIDs[0];
            const allItemsIds = allItemsObjs.map(obj => obj.id);

            if (collectedItemsIDs != undefined && collectedItemsIDs.length > 0) {

                const pointItemsID = collectedItemsIDs
                    .filter((item_id: number) => allItemsIds.includes(item_id))
                    .map((item_id: number) => {
                        return {
                            item_id,
                            point_id: insertedPointID,
                        }
                    });

                return trx('points_items').insert(pointItemsID)
            }
            else {

                return Promise.resolve([]);
            }
        }).catch(err => Promise.reject(err))
    })
        .then()
        .catch()
}
```

It's called here

```
console.log(`calling method`);
newPoint.store(items_id)
    .then(() => {

        response.status(200).json({ mensagem: "Novo Ponto de coleta cadastrado com successo" });
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {

        response.status(400).json({ outside_catch: error });
    })
```

I added the property count to see how many times that method was being called. I got as an output:

```
calling method
1
2
3
Error: insert into`points`(`city`, `count`, `email`, `image`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `name`, `store`, `uf`, `whatsapp`) values('', 3, 'coleta@org.com.br', '', 19.87, 124.8, 'Oraganizacao', (select *), '', '+55 19 999876321') - SQLITE_ERROR: table points has no column named count
(node: 16505) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: insert into`points`(`city`, `count`, `email`, `image`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `name`, `store`, `uf`, `whatsapp`) values('', 3, 'coleta@org.com.br', '', 19.87, 124.8, 'Oraganizacao', (select *), '', '+55 19 999876321') - SQLITE_ERROR: table points has no column named count
(node: 16505) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag`--unhandled-rejections=strict`(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 5)
[ERROR] 13: 08: 12 Error: insert into`points`(`city`, `count`, `email`, `image`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `name`, `store`, `uf`, `whatsapp`) values('', 3, 'coleta@org.com.br', '', 19.87, 124.8, 'Oraganizacao', (select *), '', '+55 19 999876321') - SQLITE_ERROR: table points has no column named count
4
(node: 16505) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: insert into`points`(`city`, `count`, `email`, `image`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `name`, `store`, `uf`, `whatsapp`) values('', 4, 'coleta@org.com.br', '', 19.87, 124.8, 'Oraganizacao', (select *), '', '+55 19 999876321') - SQLITE_ERROR: table points has no column named count
(node: 16505) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag`--unhandled-rejections=strict`(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 8)
5
(node: 16505) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: insert into`points`(`city`, `count`, `email`, `image`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `name`, `store`, `uf`, `whatsapp`) values('', 5, 'coleta@org.com.br', '', 19.87, 124.8, 'Oraganizacao', (select *), '', '+55 19 999876321') - SQLITE_ERROR: table points has no column named count
(node: 16505) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag`--unhandled-rejections=strict`(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 11)
6
```

Comment: FYI, there is no point at all to this: `.catch(err => Promise.reject(err))`.  It's just wasted code.

Comment: And, what are these doing `.then().catch()` all by themselves?  Should be removed as they aren't useful.

Comment: Where's the calling code that calls `StorePoint()`?

Comment: Please don't use `this` as variable name. It already refers to function's internal context.

Comment: @jfriend00
I've assigned StorePoint to store method:
`class Points {
store = StorePoint.bind(this);}`
And the only part which I call for this is ate that second code block right after console.log(`calling method`).... About the .then and .catch, I know I was just trying to get rid of the error.

Comment: @MikaelLepistö It seems like in typescript I must do that so a random function may have a `this`

Comment: It's pretty hard to keep people engaged in a conversation and keep context fresh in mind when you come back 7-8 days later and were completely silent after first engagement.